# Highcharts - how to update series in angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have a problem with an update series data in column chart. At the beginning, when my model is empty I set an empty array as the series and then in `ngOnchanges` method I map my `modelData` to matching format. Unfortunately, the chart is still empty.
        Here is my component code:

```
        export class ColumnChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
        highcharts = Highcharts;
        chartConstructor: string;
        @Input() dataModel: MyChartModel[];

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.initChart();
        }

        ngOnChanges(): void {
            this.chartOptions = {
                series: this.getData()
            };        
        }

        private initChart(): void {
            this.highcharts = Highcharts;
            this.chartConstructor = "chart";
            this.chartOptions = {
                chart: {
                    type: "column"
                }
                //...
                // others settings
                //...
                series: []
            };
        }



        getData(){
        // some methods to map from dataModel to expected array
        // finally return something like this:
        return [{
            data: [2134000, 3168818, 2569759],
            name: 2015,
            type: "column"`enter code here`
        },{
            data: [2497680, 3195299, 2480444],
            name: 2014,
            type: "column"
        },{
            data: [2872000, 3604271, 2925828],
            name: 2016,
            type: "column"
        }]
    }
```

And finally chart is empty. What's interesting, when I set `series: [{}]` in `initChart()` method, chart show one series. If I set `series: [{},{}]` chart will show two series, etc. But I don't know how many series will be in my `dataModel`, so I cannot set the array with a suitable count of objects in the array.

I have tried use `this.chartOptions.series.push(myObject)` but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Please have a look at the below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54434961/7397820

Answer (score 6):

I've made a simple online example for you with highcharts update in Angular app. I've used `highcharts-angular` official Highcharts wrapper which I recommend you (it can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular). Check the code and demo posted below:

**app.module.ts :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { ChartComponent } from "./chart.component";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ChartComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HighchartsChartModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**chart.component.html :**

```
<div class="boxChart__container">
  <div>
    <highcharts-chart
      id="container"
      [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
      [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
      [(update)]="updateFromInput"
      [oneToOne]="true"
      style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
    >
    </highcharts-chart>

    <button (click)="onInitChart()">Init Chart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**chart.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html"
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "app";
  chart;
  updateFromInput = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "chart";
  chartCallback;
  chartOptions = {
    series: [],
    exporting: {
      enabled: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: "Data"
      }
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    // saving chart reference using chart callback
    this.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onInitChart() {
    const self = this,
      chart = this.chart;

    chart.showLoading();
    setTimeout(() => {
      chart.hideLoading();

      self.chartOptions.series = [
        {
          data: [2134000, 3168818, 2569759],
          name: 2015,
          type: "column"
        },
        {
          data: [2497680, 3195299, 2480444],
          name: 2014,
          type: "column"
        },
        {
          data: [2872000, 3604271, 2925828],
          name: 2016,
          type: "column"
        }
      ];

      self.updateFromInput = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Demo:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/kw94l52z55