# How to use add series and update methods in the high chart wrapper for angular?

Tags: highcharts, angular5

I am using high chart wrapper in my angular5 app with the help of below link.

[high chart wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular)

but how can I use addSeries() to add series into the existing chart and how can I update the properties of existing chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I use addSeries() to add series into the existing chart and
>   how can I update the properties of existing chart.

When using `highcharts-angular` wrapper it is not recommended to use chart methods like `addSeries()` or `update()` directly on chart reference.

You have to update a whole component, not only chart properties. It can be achieved by updating chartOptions object (add new series, point, title etc) and setting `updateFlag = true`. Check the code and demo posted below.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { ChartComponent } from "./chart.component";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ChartComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HighchartsChartModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**chart.component.html:**

```
<div class="boxChart__container">
  <div>
    <highcharts-chart
      id="container"
      [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
      [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
      [(update)]="updateFlag"
      [oneToOne]="true"
      style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
    >
    </highcharts-chart>
    <button (click)="updateChart()">Update Chart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**chart.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html"
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "app";
  chart;
  updateFlag = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "chart";
  chartCallback;
  chartOptions = {
    series: [
      {
        data: [1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
      }
    ],
    exporting: {
      enabled: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: "Data"
      }
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    this.chartCallback = chart => {
      // saving chart reference
      self.chart = chart;
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  updateChart() {
    const self = this,
      chart = this.chart;

    chart.showLoading();
    setTimeout(() => {
      chart.hideLoading();

      self.chartOptions.series = [
        {
          data: [10, 25, 15]
        },
        {
          data: [12, 15, 10]
        }
      ];

      self.chartOptions.title = {
        text: "Updated title!"
      };

      self.updateFlag = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/oomo7424pz

**Docs reference:**

- updateFlag - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details

Comment: Great answer, but I'm gonna abandon using this library right now for chart.js. What the

Answer (score -1):

here is a very useful answer for learning how to updata a highchart.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/chart-update

it explains a method chart.update

```
 chart.update({
    chart: {
      inverted: false,
      polar: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Plain'
    }
  });
```

For adding series the following method is used

```
chart.addSerie(serie,true);
```

flag 'true' here is equivalent to `chart.redraw();`

OR

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
chart.addSeries({                        
    name: array.name,
    data: array.value
});
```

If you are going to add several series you should set the redraw flag to false and then call redraw manually after as that will be much faster.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
chart.addSeries({                        
    name: 'Bill',
    data: [1,2,4,6]
}, false);
chart.addSeries({                        
    name: 'John',
    data: [4,6,4,6]
}, false);
chart.redraw();
```

For more information and methods you can visit the Official Highcharts API page:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart

When using angular-highcharts wrapper as
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';

create charts as below

```
  chart = new Chart({
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Linechart'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Line 1',
        data: [1, 2, 3]
      }
    ]
  });
```

now you can call all API methods on this

Comment: in high chart wrapper it create chart intance like chart = Highcharts. and it's not having the properties of addserie()

Comment: @federer Please check the updated answer above, i have added a solution at the end