# HighCharts. Angular. Redraw Chart with new Series on Event Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

kind of stuck in a hole here. I have a stacked Highchart that I'm trying to re-render when you click on a button. Here is what it looks like for now:

[image]

Clicking on any of the buttons will trigger a designated event handler that helps me generate a new series of data for that particular category. The data is organized in a way that bar-charts can consume.

For instance, clicking on the "Asset Class" button will return an output of:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Cash", data: Array(1)}
1: {name: "Equity", data: Array(1)}
2: {name: "Fixed Income", data: Array(1)}
3: {name: "Fund", data: Array(1)}
length: 4
```

The problem I'm having is that the chart never seems to update even though I'm updating the series data. (this.chart.options.series = myNewSeries)

Some events will return more than 4 items (could be anywhere from 4 to 30 values) and I need them to stack as well.

Here is my code with the updating logic near the bottom:

```
export class ChartComponent{
    constructor(){
        || block of script logic ||
        this.options = {
          chart: {
            type: 'column',
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            style: {
              fontFamily: "Arial"
            },
            events: {
              redraw: function (){
                alert("The chart is being redrawn")
              }
            }
          },
          title: {
            text: ""
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: this.seriesData.category,
            labels: {
              style: {
                fontSize: "14px"
              }
            }
          },
          yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
              text: ""
            },
            labels: {
              formatter: function () {
                let valueString = (
                  this.value > 999.99 && this.value <= 999999.99 ?
                    "$" + (this.value / 1000).toFixed(0) + "K" : this.value > 999999.99 ?
                      "$" + (this.value / 1000000).toFixed(1) + "M" : this.value
                )
                return valueString
              },
              style: {
                fontSize: "14px",
              }
            }

          },
          legend: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            verticalAlign: "top",
            align: "right",
            layout: "vertical",
            itemStyle: {
              fontSize: "16px",
              color: "#6c6c6c",
            },
            symbolPadding: 8,
            itemMarginTop: 10,
            shadow: false,
            labelFormatter: function () {
              return `${this.name}`
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
              let name = this.series.name
              let value = this.y
              let valueString = `$${value.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}`
              let total = this.point.stackTotal
              let percentage = ((value / total) * 100).toFixed(2)
              let percentageString = `(${percentage})%`

              return `<b>${name}</b> <br> ${valueString} ${percentageString}`
            },
            style: {
              fontSize: "14px",
            },
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
          },
          plotOptions: {
            column: {
              stacking: 'normal',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              }
            },
            series: {
              pointWidth: 100,
              borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
            }
          },
          series: this.seriesData.series
        }
    }
    options: Object

  saveInstance(chartInstance): void {
     this.chart = chartInstance;
  }

  updateSeriesData = (data: Array<any>, title): void => {
    this.chart.options.series = data
    this.chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: title})
  }

  // event handlers
  getIndustryData = (e) => {
    let newSeries = this.getSeriesTotals("Industry", "SecuritySectorLevel1", "SecuritySectorLevel2")
    this.updateSeriesData([...newSeries.series], newSeries.category)
  }
  getSectorData = (e) => {
    let newSeries = this.getSeriesTotals("Sector", "SecuritySectorLevel2", "SecuritySectorLevel1")
    this.updateSeriesData([...newSeries.series], newSeries.category)
  }
  getAssetClassData = (e) =>{
    let newSeries = this.getSeriesTotals("Asset Class", "AssetClassLevel1", "SecuritySectorLevel1")
    this.updateSeriesData([...newSeries.series], newSeries.category)
  }
  getRegionData = (e) => {
    let newSeries = this.getSeriesTotals("Region", "CountryOfRisk", "CountryOfIssuance")
    this.updateSeriesData([...newSeries.series], newSeries.category)
  }
  getCurrencyData = (e) =>{
    let newSeries = this.getSeriesTotals("Currency", "LocalCCY", "LocalCCYDescription")
    this.updateSeriesData([...newSeries.series], newSeries.category)
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434380/how-to-use-add-series-and-update-methods-in-the-high-chart-wrapper-for-angular/54437065#54437065. If it won't help you please be more precise and try to elaborate an online example of your app (simplified), thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, for the next person who surfs here:
In your HTML-Element you'll have something like:

```
<highcharts-chart
...
[(update)]="updateFlag">
</highcharts-chart>
```

And in the corresponding Typescript file you have a

```
updateFlag = false;
```

and after the section where you've changed something, you do:

```
this.updateFlag = true;
```