# Add and Remove data into Bar chart and Pie chart in Highchart Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using highchart in angular application and I want to add new data and remove prev data into bar chart and pie chart when click on button, but the thing is that I don't want to redraw the chart again during adding and removing data.

Comment: Please share code

Comment: @Çağrı, Here is the demo code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-framework-181um?file=/src/app/app.component.ts
right now when I adding new series, the current series still into it which is not I want. I want when I add new series the prev series should be remove. And there is only one series right now but what should I do when there is multiple series?

Comment: @MueedUllah 1. You should use the official highcharts-angular wrapper which is fully supported by our team. 2. Here is an instruction how to update the series: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328513/highcharts-how-to-update-series-in-angular